# Why does boost not have a make_scoped()?

Tags: c++, boost, make-shared, scoped-ptr

Boost's [`make_shared()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html) function promises to be exception-safe while attempting to create a `shared_ptr`.

**Why is there no `make_scoped()` equivalent?  Is there a common best practice?**

Here's a code example from the [`boost::scoped_ptr` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) that seems unsafe to me:

```
    boost::scoped_ptr<Shoe> x(new Shoe);
```

This line of code will do these three things **in order**:

- Allocate heap memory for `Shoe`
- Call the constructor for `Shoe`
- Call the constructor for `boost::scoped_ptr<Shoe>`

If the constructor for `Shoe` throws an exception,  <strike>memory will be leaked.</strike> *(see R. Martinho Fernandes answer)*  The `scoped_ptr` won't handle the deallocation because it hasn't been constructed yet.

Is this an oversight?  Or is there a solution that I've failed to notice?

Comment: This example is safe, but one that is not: `f(boost::scoped_ptr<Shoe>(new Shoe), g());`.  The coding practice to solve the issue: Always name smart pointers as variables or members, don't construct them as temporary subexpressions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the constructor fails, no memory is leaked. That's part of the semantics of `new`, no smart pointers involved:

```
struct Foo { Foo() { throw 23; } };
new Foo(); // no memory leaked
```

The added exception safety provided by `make_shared` comes from when you're initializing two `shared_ptr`s in an expression and *the two initializations are not sequenced*, as is the case in function call arguments:

```
struct Bar {
    Bar(bool fail) {
        if(fail) throw 17;
    }
}
f(shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar(true)), shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar(false)));
```

Since there is no sequencing between the evaluations of `new Bar(true)`, `shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar(true))`, `new Bar(false)` and `shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar(false))`, the following could happen:

1. `new Bar(false)` is evaluated and succeeds: memory is allocated;
2. `new Bar(true)` is evaluated and fails: it doesn't leak memory resulting from this evaluation;

No `shared_ptr` was constructed at this time, and so the memory allocated in #1 is now leaked.

Comment: Does this sound like I understand you?  `new` promises to catch exceptions thrown from the constructor, free the memory, then re-throw?

Comment: @Drew: Yes, something to that effect. If you're interested, this is described in the standard on §5.3.4 paragrah 18.

Comment: For completeness another purpose of `make_shared` (in most implementations) is that it allocates memory for the reference count at the same as time as the object created (allocates one block big enough for the object and the count) so that you don't incur the performance penalty if two heap allocations. The `scoped_ptr` (or `unique_ptr` in c++11 don't need a reference count and therefore don't gain anything from it in that department.

Answer (score 15):

`scoped_ptr` predates move semantics and is noncopyable by design.  Thus, `make_scoped` would be impossible to implement because in order to return an object from a function, its type must either be movable or copyable.

Comment: To be clear: since C++11 it is possible to return non-copyable, non-movable object from a function: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GLIgM5nA9ROJahvk
But like you pointed, scoped_ptr predated `c++11` ant that is the clue here.

Answer (score 1):

If Shoe throws then Shoe isn't constructed so there is nothing scoped_ptr can really do. No?
The scoped_ptr x is on the stack and will get cleaned up on scope exit.